# split string into two and stored it in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, split

getting error when i split the string using substring function in vb.net.it shows the error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
code

 phone = t1("fld_phone").ToString
 if phone <> String.Empty Then
   msg = t1("fld_msg")
    msg1 = msg.Length
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0
     For i = 0 To msg.Length - 1 Step 150
      strarr(Counter) = msg.Substring(i, 150)
       Counter += 1
       Next


the len of the msg variable is 312 char.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wheres the code with you using the split function?

Comment: sorry using substring function

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be just splitting it in two why use a for statement, just take the length of your string divide by 2 and use that for the end of you first substring and begining of the second. Also if you do not have `Option Strict` turned on you should. As It's Your Fault states make sure you have intitialize all of your Variables expecially strarr.

i.e.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim strArr(1) As String
        Dim msg As String = "123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D"

        strarr(0) = msg.Substring(0, msg.Length \ 2)
        strArr(1) = msg.Substring(msg.Length \ 2)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that **strarr** is an initialized array; according to that code, that should be the location of the error.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the for loop. you are increasing counter 150 every time the loop execute. after first loop i set to  149. in second time of execution i equals  299. this is less then 312 and only 13 char left and you are taking string up to next 150 char.
That's why it is showing error.